# mvn release:prepare failing while git push operation?

Tags: git, maven, pom.xml, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to release one component using the maven. This is the project structure:

```
root-
    A-project/pom.xml
    B-project/pom.xml
    C-project/pom.xml
    D-project/pom.xml
```

Here we have ssh URL `ssh://userID@gerritforge.lmera.companyName.se:29418/root` up to `root` only. So we add the following lines of code in each project to give the relative path.

```
<pomFileName>A-project/pom.xml</pomFileName>
```

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>perform</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <pomFileName>A-project/pom.xml</pomFileName>
                <!--
                <pushChanges>false</pushChanges>
                -->
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <!--
    <configuration>
        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
    </configuration>
    -->
</plugin>
```

While running `mvn release:prepare` the project is building successfully but after this I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] Unable to tag SCM
Provider message:
The git-push command failed.
Command output:
To ssh://userID@gerritforge.lmera.companyName.se:29418/root
 ! [remote rejected] A-prject-template-1.1.12 -> A-prject-template-1.1.12 \
 (prohibited by Gerrit) error: failed to push some refs to \
 'ssh://userID@gerritforge.lmera.companyName.se:29418/root'
```

No tags are present at local and remote before doing `mvn release:prepare`.

Comment: What does this message: `(prohibited by Gerrit)` says ?

Comment: are you sure your local repo is up to date? Looks to me that there are remote commits you don't have locally yet. rebase/pull to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I got same Gerrit failure with maven-release-plugin using Git on Jenkins.

- Push pom.xml -> Gerrit SUCCESS
- Local tag SUCCESS
- Push tag -> Gerrit FAIL "... (prohibited by Gerrit)"

SOLUTION:  Gerrit permission "Forge Committer",
see https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-prohibited-by-gerrit.html

Reason:  Jenkins userid which created the tag was not the same as the userid for push to Gerrit.